# Sending Multicast Packet from Win7 Pro vs Ultimate

Tags: c#, multicast, udpclient

I have two development rigs, one running windows 7 Ultimate (laptop) and one running windows 7 Professional (Desktop). I just checked out code on my desktop that worked perfectly on my laptop to send a udp packet over multicast (below) and it works on my Win7 Ultimate computer just fine, as well as a win2k3 server, and windows xp machine that I could test it on, but on my win7 Pro box I get the following SocketException "An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full"

Does windows 7 Pro not allow you to send multicast packets? Or am I just missing something?

```
var socket = new UdpClient("239.7.23.1", 6567);
var testBuf = new byte[] {12, 24};
socket.Send(testBuf, 2);
```

Update: I forgot to mention I disabled all firewalls, and the driver is the Intel provided driver, and in going through the Advanced properties of the device, I verified the Receive and Transmit Buffers are both set to 2048, and I have tried the above test code with between 2 and 256 byte payloads, all with the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many possibilities for this, so while I don't have a specific answer, maybe it will help at least troubleshoot.

First off, the code *should* work for both systems.

Is it possible that your NIC on your desktop is cheaper/lower end and doesn't have as much buffer allocated to it for the nic queue?  That is generally a NIC model specific feature (sort of like getting a PC with X amount of L2 Cache - different models have different cache buffers).  How about driver differences in the buffer allocations? Are you using manuf drivers or microsoft's?  Try different drivers and/or updating it to the latest manuf driver instead of microsoft's version if you're using that.

Did you verify the firewalls were disabled on both and the windows firewall was not set differently on each system.  Are they on different routers?  If so, is it possible multicasting is disabled on one router, but not the other?  Could be a lot going on to cause this so it could be a lot of things that can cause this problem.  HTH.

Comment: These are all good suggestions - I updated my question to include that the firewalls are disabled and the send/receive buffers on the device are 2048 bytes, so that should not be a problem. Is it possible this NIC cannot support multicast? I thought that was handled in the IP stack within windows?

Comment: Turns out the NIC in the new computer did not support Multicast - was not aware that a nic could prevent multicast from working.